# Call own method in jQuery queue

Tags: jquery, methods, call, undefined

I have created my own method in jQuery with:

```
$.fn.plop = function(){
    // Method 
};
```

And I'm trying to call it in a queue like:

```
$(elems[0]).plop().delay(800).fadeOut();
```

But Firefox return the error:

> TypeError: $(...).plop(...) is undefined

Any idea on what is causing the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Does .plop() return a jQuery object?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, in my case I was only needing to call a basic JavaScript function.

So I use ".animate({opacity: 1},{step: function() {plop();}})" in the queue, and that call my function plop().

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be chainable you need to return jQuery in your function. Simply `return $;` if nothing else.

Example:

```
$.fn.plop = function(){
    // Method
    return this.html('bar'); // html() returns jQuery
};

$('#myDiv').plop().delay(800).fadeOut();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mUuhF/

Answer (score 0):

To extend jQuery properly, you need to write your methods like this:

```
$.fn.plop = function () {  
    return this.each(function () {

        // Do something for each element

    });
};
```

This will allow you to run .plop() on any collection of jQuery elements, applying the behavior or action to each element, and it will return the original collection so that you may continue to chain additional method calls to it.